# Parameter type not valid, stored procedure call IBM DB2

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, db2

I am trying to invoke a stored procedure from IBM DB2 database with Java code, This is the callable statement:

```
CallableStatement cstmt = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;
BigDecimal bg1;
bg1 = new BigDecimal("99999");
cstmt = conn.prepareCall("CALL SPNAME (?,?,?,?)");
cstmt.setString(1, getFIRST());
cstmt.setString(2, getSECOND()); 
cstmt.setBigDecimal(3, bg1); 
cstmt.setString(4, getOUTPUTFIRST()); 
cstmt.setQueryTimeout(getTimeout());
resultSet = cstmt.executeQuery();

ResultSetMetaData rsmd = resultSet.getMetaData();
int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();

while (resultSet.next()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
        if (i > 1) 
            System.out.print(",  ");
        String columnValue = resultSet.getString(i);

        ORDERLIST+=resultSet.getString(i) + "| ";
        if ( (i % 9) == 0 ) {
            ORDERLIST+=resultSet.getString(i) + " ~ "; 
        }
    }
}

OUTPUTFIRST=cstmt.getString(4);
```

The third parameter in the Stored procedure is decimal. All of the others are strings.

I am getting on output the following response:

msg: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter type not valid.

Can someone advise?

Comment: is the count of params being passed matching actual count

Comment: This is the error when I am not passing the right count of parameters: <Msg>While executing [invoke] encountered [java.sql.SQLException] : [[SQL0440] Routine SPNAMEin *N not found with specified parameters. at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:687)]</Msg> 

And the Parameter type not valid is different error.

Comment: how is was your stored procedure created?

Comment: I don't know, it was already created. I am just invoking it.

Answer (score 0):

As you are setting and calling getString on the 4th parameter, presumably the parameter mode is INOUT, in which can you must both set it and register it. Try

```
cstmt.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.CHAR);
cstmt.setString(4, getOUTPUTFIRST());
```